# Can non-cyclic one-relator groups be finite?

Tags: group-theory

The answer appears to be no, but I can't find it anywhere.

Worded another way, do there exist subgroups of finite index in the free group $F_2$ on two generators $x,y$ which is normally generated by a single element?

It's clear that if the single element is a possible generator then the normal closure must be infinite index. However, what about elements which lie in characteristic subgroups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. A group defined by a presentation with more generators that relations is infinite, because its abelianization (i.e. the abelian group defined by this presentation) is infinite. This is just elementary linear algebra. See for example [Finitely presented Group with less relations than Generators.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478841)

So if a presentation has more than one generator and just one relation then it defines an infite group.